# Why can't I import static java.lang.System.out.println?

Tags: java

It seems strange that I can't import static java.lang.System.out.println, when I can import static java.lang.Math.abs.  Is there some reason behind this or am I doing something really stupid that I don't see at the moment?  (Using Eclipse.)

Comment: Instead of importing it statically (which doesn't work as you've found out) you can just type "sysout" and eclipse will replace it with System.out.println()

Comment: @Voo "sout" in NetBeans and IntelliJ, which I personally prefer even though "sysout" seems more logical and meaningful...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`Math` is a class, on which `abs` is a static method. `System.out` is a static field rather than a class. So its `println` method isn't actually a static method, but an instance method on a static field.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can, instead, `import static java.lang.System.out` and from thereon just go `out.println()`.

Comment: @AlistairA.Israel, Why isn't the `java.lang` part optional?

Comment: @Pacerier: Since the `import` statement's purpose is to specify where things are coming from in the first place (when there could be similarly-named classes and such in different packages), they require the package name to be specified.

Comment: What is the reasonable decision of making `System.out` a static field rather than a class?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: One benefit is that they can reuse the `PrintStream` class to handle the logic and structure for `System.err` and `System.out`. You can also pass `out` or `err` as arguments to methods that are written more generally against `OutputStream`, `Appendable`, or `PrintStream`. There are probably other benefits as well that don't come to mind right away.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

Because `java.lang.System.out` is a [static object (a PrintStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) on which you call `println`.

Though in eclipse you can type `sysout` and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> to have it expanded to `System.out.println();`

Comment: Nice Eclipse tip there @ratchet freak.

Comment: `sout` for IntelliJ

Comment: You can use `sout` for eclipse too. (At least in oxygen).

Answer (score 12):

Non-static methods cannot be imported that way.

However, you can do this:

```
public static void println(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o);
}

// elsewhere
println("Hello World");     // can be inlined
```

Comment: what does inlined mean here?

Comment: @Thufir When a method is, it code is placed inside the calling code and optimised.  The significance is that this has no overhead.

Answer (score 10):

[Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey)'s answer seems to be the best work around. But without arguments the use cases are a bit limited.

```
static<T> void println(T arg) { System.out.println(arg); }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @curtisk it is neither critique nor a request for clarification. It is just a more practical alternative.

Comment: a tad old but why generic instead of just `Object`?

Answer (score 4):

**Note:**`import static` only works on a static field or a static method of a class.

You can't `import static java.lang.System.out.println`, because `println` method is not a static method of any class(`out` is not even a class,it is an instance of `PrintStream`).

You can `import static java.lang.Math.abs`, because `abs` method is a static method of Class `Math`.

My suggestion is that since `out` is a static field of `System`(which is a class), you can `import static java.lang.System.out`, and then in your code you can use `out.println` instead of `System.out.println` for short.

Answer (score 4):

Combine printf and println

```
public static void println(Object format, Object... args) {
    System.out.printf(format.toString(), args);
    System.out.println();
}

@Test
public void testPrintln(){
    println(100);
    println("abc");
    println(new Date());
    println("%s=%d","abc",100);
}
```

output

```
100
abc
Wed Nov 01 22:24:20 CST 2017
abc=100
```

Comment: Alough it is not related to the question , but it did provide an alternative way for the shortand of System.out.println. I like this :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
package example.tools;

public class ShowMe {
    /*public static void print(String arg) {
       System.out.println(arg);
    }*/
    // or better as ceving's example
    public static<T> void print(T arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

In another class

```
import static example.tools.ShowMe.*;
    public class Flower {
        Flower() {
            print("Rose");
        }
    }
```