# Eclipse error : println method undefined even with sytem library imported

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse Kepler and I wrote this function :

```
import java.lang.System.out.*;
public class Human {
public void speak() {
      println("Hello!");
}
}
```

Eclipse tell me that the println method is undefined! When I replace it by System.out.println() there is no problem.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277757/why-cant-i-import-static-java-lang-system-out-println

Comment: what is your question..?

Comment: @SumitSingh It seems the question is why System.out.println() works fine, but importing java.lang.System.out.* and using println() does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since println method is not static, you can not use that in static import

you can try the below

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Human {
public void speak() {
      out.println("Hello!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` isn't a package, it's a variable, and you can't import individual instance methods from other objects. You could theoretically *statically import* the `out` variable, since `System` is a non-instantiated class:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

...
    out.println("Hello!");
```

But this isn't especially useful, and it will be very confusing to most Java programmers. The standard usage is to simply write `System.out` wherever you're wanting to print to the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

use static keyowrd for system like

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `println`method isn't a static method, its an instance method on a static field.
But if you want to call is like `println("Hello!");` you can do this like following:

```
public static void println() {
    System.out.println();
}

println();     // can be inlined
```